# setting values for nested JSON in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a Json which looks like following

```
{
    "Market": 0,
    "Marketer": null,
    "Notes": null,
    "SalesChannel": null,
    "ServiceLocations": [
        {
            "ExtensionData": null,
            "AdminFee": 0,
            "CommodityType": 0,
            "ContractType": 0,
            "Payment": {
                "ExtensionData": null,
                "BankAccountNumber": null,
                "BankAccountType": 0,
                "BankRoutingNumber": null,
                "CardType": 0,
                "CreditCardExpirationDate": "/Date(-62135575200000)/",
                "CreditCardNumber": null,
                "CreditCardReferenceID": null,
                "CreditCardSecurityCode": null,
                "PaymentAddress1": null,
                "PaymentAddress2": null,
                "PaymentAmount": 0,
                "PaymentCity": null,
                "PaymentCounty": null,
                "PaymentFirstName": null,
                "PaymentLastName": null,
                "PaymentPhone": null,
                "PaymentState": null,
                "PaymentType": 0,
                "PaymentZip": null
            },
            "ProductID": null,
            "PromoCode": null,
            "Rate": 0,
            "RateSchedule": null,
            "ServiceAddress1": null,
            "ServiceAddress2": null,
            "ServiceCity": null
        }
    ],
    "SocialSecurityNumber": null,
    "SubAgent": null,
    "Login": null
}
```

I want to dynamically loop through the the JSON and set the values of each key value pairs. if the value is present set the value but if the value is not present then leave it as is.

im doing something like this because this doesnt seem to work

```
$.getJSON("data.js",function buildjson(json){
                myJSONObject = json;
                        for (var key in myJSONObject) {
                                    if(myJSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                                    if(typeof(myJSONObject[key]) === 'object')
                                    {
                                    newJson(myJSONObject[key]);
                                    }

                                    if($("#main").find(":input[name="+key+"]") != "") {
                                    modifyJson(key,myJSONObject[key]);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                    setData(key,myJSONObject[key]);
                                    }
                                    $("#keylist").append(key+":"+myJSONObject[key]+"<br />");
                                    //newJson(myJSONObject[key]);
                                }
                    }
                function newJson(myJSONObject) {
                    for (var key in myJSONObject) {
                                        if(myJSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                                        modifyJson(key,myJSONObject[key]);
                                        newJson(myJSONObject[key]);
                                    }
                        }
        }
        function setData(path, value) {
    if (path.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        path = path.split('.');
        for (var i = 0, l = path.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (typeof(data[path[i]]) === 'object') {
                continue;
            } else {
                data[path[i - 1]][path[i]] = value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        data[path] = value;
    }
};

            function modifyJson(key,value) {
                var theValue = value;
                //$("#keylist1").append(key+":"+theValue+"<br />");
                if($("#main").find(":input[name="+key+"]")) {
                    theValue = $(":input[name="+key+"]").val();
                    setData(key,theValue);
                }
            }

    });

    }
```

What modification do i need to do?

Comment: You don't need to `eval()` the data returned by `getJSON()`

Comment: im not using eval it was just there in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma after `"ServiceCity": null` which is causing an invalid JSON object.

Comment: This was no the complete json i have removed the comma. this code still doesnt work i need to set the values looping through this json.